# Write byte array on video file in SD Card

Tags: android, video, arrays, sd-card, streamwriter

I am trying to write byte array to video file in SD Card but i am getting an error. I am posting code with error also. Please give me any suggestions what should i do.

Code Here:-

```
file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+    "/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");
final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
Thread r1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (counter == 0) {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                counter++;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = mediaPlayer.getCurrentFrame();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            fileOutputStream.write(byteArray);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException nle) {
            nle.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (handler1 != null) {
            handler1.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
    }
};
r1.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error Here:-

```
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:455)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
at com.vvdn.android.dvr.SurfaceViewFragment$2.run(SurfaceViewFragment.java:503)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:202)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:197)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:450)
... 12 more
```

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I have updated code also. So please have a look.

Comment: Could you have any concurrency or threading issue here?  It's a little worrisome that variables such as counter are apparently global.

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because the file did not exist, try adding

```
file1.createNewFile();
```

before you start writing to it.

Comment: I wondered about that too, but the documentation for the FileOutputStream(File) constructor says it will create the File if it does not exist.

Comment: Hmmm. I am pretty sure that was the issue I was having, but I could be mistaken. If I get a chance I'll try to test it again.